# fractional compact Sobolev embedding on lipschitz domain

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain. It is well known that $H^1(\Omega)$ can be compactly embedded into $L^2(\Omega)$. I also found references for the compact embedding $H^\delta(\Omega)\hookrightarrow L^2(\Omega)$, where $0<\delta<1$.

The following is my question. IS the embedding $H^1(\Omega)\hookrightarrow H^\delta(\Omega)$ compact? If so, is there any reference?

Comment: See [this related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259579/fractional-order-rellich-kondrashov-theorem). (Note that the $W^{s,2}$ and the $H^s$ scale coincide, on $R^n$ in general and on $\Omega$ because of your supposed Lipschitz regularity.) Essentially, you want to obtain a multiplicative inequality $\|u\|_{H^\delta(\Omega)} \leq C \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^{1-\delta} \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^\delta$, from which your desired compactness follows via Rellich-Kondrachov.

Comment: Great. The multiplicative/interpolation inequality is quite instructive. In fact, I found related theorems from page 26, "Elliptic problems in nonsmooth domains" by Pierre Grisvard.